# Install .tar.gz and .tar files?

Tags: installation, gnome, tar, gzip

Cody again. I'm still sort of a noob at installing things so I need your help... Im trying to install hping3 and of course it's a .tar.gz file... I've looked everywhere even on here and no solutions... Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, it should be already available in Ubuntu repositories (12.10), so simply do this:

```
sudo apt-get install hping3
```

In case that it's really tar.gz, then you can extract it by using:
    tar -xvzf hping3.tar.gz

Then, you have to compile the source code, typically by using "make" command (you'll need installing the build tools):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Take this as a hint ;-).

Answer (score 2):

the above answer is an easy and efficient solution but if you want to install through tar.gz first you need to extract is using

```
tar -xvvf [filename.tar.gz]
```

then you need to configure the source code contained in tar.gz with command

```
./configure
```

after that do

```
make
make install
```

to install your program and you are done.

PS: you need to be present in the specific folder extracted. that's all.